# Does compare-and-swap implemented by high level language atomic

Tags: compare-and-swap

Suppose to implement a function called Atom by the compare-and-swap mechanism in a high-level language like c++ or java without using the atomically instruction of X86, then the function would be atomic or not.

```cpp
int Atom(int* reg, int old_val, int new_val)
{
  int old_reg_val = *reg;
  if (old_reg_val == old_val)
     *reg = new_val;
  return old_reg_val;
}
```

Comment: another thread can change value `*reg` after you assigned it to `old_reg_val`, so this function is not atomic

Comment: @IłyaBursov Make that the answer.